# Matlab reading data from Excel

Tags: matlab, import-from-excel

I have the following line of code and what I am able to understand is that it reads data from an Excel sheet(which consists of many columns). However, why are two variable, i.e. xlsnodata and xlstextdata, required?

```
 [xlsnodata, xlstextdata] = xlsread('data.xls');
```

Comment: You can specify whether you want the data contained in the spreadsheet as number, text, or everything. In your case you will load numbers and text data.

Comment: in what sense? I have for example age and then a column with the integers. If I do 1 variable I will not get "age"?

Comment: if you only supply 1 output argument you get the numbers by default. Look [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/import-a-worksheet-or-range.html) for more info that should answer your questions :)

Comment: Great! I think you could delete the question since it was more of a comprehension problem than a programming bug. Good luck!